# Android SMS Timer

Tags: android, timer, sms, verification

Ok guys, I need the brightest minds on this. I am still a novice prorammer for android, but I have been asked to try to creat an app that will allow users to delay the send of their Text Messages.

I.E. when app is running, and I send a message it does not send right away but waits for a minute or two and then asks if you really want to send it; like a verification.

I am not asking for code, but for references which will allow me to read and then construct the code. Is such a service feasible?

Here is what the app needs to access:

- SMS service ( to prevent outgoing SMS until ready)
- Contact ( for whitelist)
- Ringtones on the phone.

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than override the regular workings of Android's SMS service you should create your own SMS app that sends messages after a timed delay and user approval. The code for sending SMS from [Android is trivial](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/08/sending-sms-from-application/):

```
SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();
String number = "6508570720";
sm.sendTextMessage(number, null, "Test SMS Message", null, null);
```

The delay would be only a little bit more difficult and easily [handled with a timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html). And [getting the contacts is also simple](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/contacts.html).

Comment: You are correct that this method would be much more simple. However, the client does not want a messenger app. They simply want a control panel that will delay the sending of messages. But you are right, a messenger app is easier.

Comment: You should charge extra. ;-) But seriously, the requirement is very risky and if you do get it working it is likely to break with future Android OS releases.